# How to use a unit circle to find the phase difference between two waves?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, superposition, coherence

Two electromagnetic waves, A and B, initially have a phase difference of pi/2 rad with time periods of T. A is travelling to the left while B is travelling to the right. What will be their phase differences after T/8 , 3T/8, and T/6 seconds?

I want to learn how to do this using a unit circle, and by using wave equations. Also, why is it that at any particular instant in time, the phase difference between the waves at a point in space 8 m from the source is the same as the phase difference between the waves at any other point in space?

Comment: I'm not sure there is an unambiguous answer to this. Do you consider the phase of a wave traveling to the left to be "going backwards"? Because if you don't, then the phase difference will be constant. A wave doesn't have a single phase - a particular point on a wave has a phase. Are you asking about "the same point in space, as the wave passes" or "the same point on the wave"? It doesn't give the same result...

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous wording. I meant the same point in space. Edited. And that is my biggest question : the solution given states that as the waves travel in opposite directions, their 'phases' travel in opposite directions, and thus one goes backward while the other one goes forward. But I'm having trouble visualizing how a wave travelling backward means that it's phase ( at a particular point in space ) changes 'opposite' that of the other wave.